# How to install pip and selenium and phantomjs on ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, pip

I run a python program that uses selenium and phantomjs and got these errors 2) and 3) then when I run pip install selenium i got error 1):

1) The program 'pip' is currently not installed.

2) ImportError: No module named 'selenium'

3) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.

All done on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 4):

Here are the answers:

1) sudo apt-get install python-pip

2) sudo pip install selenium

3) sudo apt-get install phantomjs

tested working. i hope it helps you.

Comment: i do not try to be "new or invention" but when i google https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stack%20overflow%20install%20phantomjs        i did not find straight forward answer for a simple question - so i doc it to help people like me.